# Opening a dialog when all regions are loaded in Shell

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

I have a WPF application using Prism framework. It has three regions that gets loaded in shell. Now, I have a requirement for which have to display a dialog once the main window(all the regions) is loaded. i.e. dialog should display on top of main window. I tried to publish an event during shell initialization,however dialog display only when I close main window or if publish the event in one of region's usercontrol constructor, it displays the dialog first and when dialog is closed main window loads. Now, am thinking if there is any way I can find if all the regions are loaded through an event then I can publish the event there.
 Questions:
1. Is there any event that I can use to detect if all the regions are loaded? 
2. Is there any other approach that you can point me to to achieve this requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in the constructor of the parent control

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Loaded, new Action(() => {code that should be executed after all children are loaded} ));
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any event that I can use to detect if all the regions are loaded?

Override `PrismApplicationBase.OnInitialized` and call the `IDialogService` from there.

Comment: Should I do this in Shellviewmodel?

Comment: Your shell view model doesn't derive from `PrismApplicationBase` and thus cannot override anything in there. You should do this in your `Application` class.